# Linker error while run on simulator works on device can some one help me resolve this?

Tags: swift, xcode

ld: warning: ignoring file /Volumes/Development 1/GitProjects///Pods/Quickblox-WebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.framework/QuickbloxWebRTC, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Volumes/Development 1/GitProjects///Pods/Quickblox-WebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.framework/QuickbloxWebRTC (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCVideoFrame", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ScreenCapture.o
  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_QBRTCVideoCapture", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC8MHDoctor13ScreenCapture in ScreenCapture.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCRemoteVideoView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCBaseSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

```
  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCCameraCapture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCVideoFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCVideoCapture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ScreenCapture.o

```
  type metadata for MHDoctor.ScreenCapture in ScreenCapture.o
  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

```
  objc-class-ref in MHTeleIncomingCallViewController.o

  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

```
  objc-class-ref in MHTeleIncomingCallViewController.o

  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o

```
  objc-class-ref in MHTeleIncomingCallViewController.o

  objc-class-ref in MHQuickBloxManager.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CallKitManager.o

```
  objc-class-ref in MHTeleCallOnGoingViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Do clean+build and build the project

Comment: I tried it dosen't work ..

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>) and then rebuild the project